# convertSendAndReceive() returns null Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue, rpc

I have been looking for a solution since morning. Why is it returning null rather than an Object? Any ideas

Consumer part takes the message but the response is Null with the `convertSendAndReceive()` method.

***RabbitMQProducer.java***

```
 private static final long DEFAULT_REPLY_TIMEOUT = 10000;

 public Object sendJsonMessage(Card card){
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(DEFAULT_REPLY_TIMEOUT);
    log.info(String.format("Message sent -> %s", card.toString()));

   return rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(exchange,routingKey, card);
}
```

***Controller***

```
 @PostMapping("/addCards")
 public ResponseEntity <String> addCards(@Valid @RequestBody Card card ){
    Object object = producer.sendJsonMessage(card);

    System.out.println( "OBJECT :" +    object);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Json message sent to RabbitMQ ..." + card.getFirstName());
}
```

***Output***

```
OBJECT :null
```